# Oracle sql selecting columns based date difference between 2 rows

Tags: sql, oracle

The relation bw 3 tables is as follows:

```
Table A

TXNID DATE AMT
123   11/1 230


Table A_Audit

TXNID Status      ChangeStatusID
123   SHIPPING     CHANGE001
123   IN-TRANSIT   CHANGE002
123   DELIVERED    CHANGE003

Table StatusChange

Status      ChangeStatusID  TimeStamp
SHIPPING     CHANGE001      Time1
IN-TRANSIT   CHANGE002      Time2
DELIVERED    CHANGE003      Time3
```

I need to get TxnID,Date and amount from Table A if status change from shipping to delivered is more than 60 mins.

I tried doing of join of 
A, A_Audit
A_Audit and Status change (Shipping)
A_Audit and Status change (Delivered)

but this is not returning any rows. Can you please give some pointers on how to proceed.

```
SELECT A.TXNID,A.DATE,A.AMT
FROM A A
JOIN A_Audit on A.TXNID = A_Audit.TXNID
JOIN StatusChange SC1 on A_Audit.ChangeStatusID=SC1.ChangeStatusID AND SC1.Status =    'Delivered'
JOIN StatusChange SC2 on A_Audit.ChangeStatusID=SC2.ChangeStatusID AND SC2.Status = 'Shipped'
WHERE datediff( 'mi', SC1.Timestamp, SC2.Timestamp )>60
```

Comment: You can't store a "time" as-is, there's no datatype to hold it so what datatype is the `time` column. What was the query you tried?

Comment: It is actually a timestamp column. I need to check that the time difference is 60 minutes

Comment: Added query that I tried

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT A.TXNID,MAX(A.DATE),MAX(AMT)
FROM A
JOIN A_Audit on A.TXNID = A_Audit.TXNID 
     AND (A_Audit.Status='SHIPPING' or A_Audit.Status='DELIVERED')
JOIN StatusChange on A_Audit.ChangeStatusID=StatusChange.ChangeStatusID
GROUP BY A.TXNID
HAVING datediff( 'mi', MIN(StatusChange.Time), MAX(StatusChange.Time) )>60
```

Comment: thank you for replying. TXN ID is the primary key in Table A. I have added the query that I am trying right now. Also it is possible that some status is still in IN-TRANSIT. So we need to make sure we consider only SHIPPED and DELIVERED status

Comment: @user1019569 I've changed query to process only SHIPPED and DELIVERED

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TXNID, "Date", AMT
FROM   A x
WHERE  EXISTS
       ( SELECT 1
         FROM   A_Audit a
                INNER JOIN
                StatusChange s
                ON (a.ChangeStatusID = s.ChangeStatusID AND a.Status = s.Status)
         WHERE  x.TXNID = a.TXNID
         GROUP BY a.TXNID
         HAVING (  MAX( DECODE( s.Status, 'DELIVERED', s."TimeStamp", null ) )
                 - MIN( DECODE( s.Status, 'SHIPPING',  s."TimeStamp", null ) ) )*24 > 1
       );
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/83357/1/0)